Distributing max operator over sum of functions
I'm taking a game theory class, and my professor uses the following step in a proof:
$$\sum_{j=2}^{N+1} \max_{s_j} f_j(x, s_j) = \max_{s_2, ..., s_{N+1}} \sum_{j=2}^{N+1} f_j(x, s_j)$$
Why is this legal? I would have though that the LHS would be $\geq$ the RHS, but not necessarily with equality, particularly because the $f_j$ can be negative.

Given two subsets $A,B\in \mathbb R$, define $A+B = { a+b: a\in A,b\in B}$. Then, what is $\max(A+B)$? Do you see that it should be $\max A + \max B$? Because we can independently maximise over $A$ and $B$. And I also think $\sup$ is a more technically correct term in general.

See this Wikipedia page for more discussion: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum
